# c# read text from pdf file (table like structure)

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I'm trying to extract particular texts from pdf and paste it into excel file. I'm using `itextsharp (LGPL version as I can't go for a paid version)` for this. I know there are lots of questions on this topic, but I couldn't find a solution in past 2 days so had to post 1. Also I'm not restricted to only iText, I'm ok with any free version of pdf library.

Below images represents my pdf file. As you can see in `page 1`, there are two tables (marked red) from which I want to extract data. I am able to extract data from these two tables. Something like this:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(name);
        int j = 0, indx = 0;
        //byte[] streamBytes = null;
        bool isFound = false;
        List<string> stringsList = new List<string>();

        try
        {
            bool br;
            string strfor = null;
            string[] ary = new string[] { };
            for (int page = 1; page <= reader.NumberOfPages; page++)
            {
                var cpage = reader.GetPageN(page);
                var content = cpage.Get(PdfName.CONTENTS);

                var ir = (PRIndirectReference)content;

                var value = reader.GetPdfObject(ir.Number);

                if (value.IsStream())
                {
                    PRStream stream = (PRStream)value;

                    var streamBytes = PdfReader.GetStreamBytes(stream);

                    var tokenizer = new PRTokeniser(new RandomAccessFileOrArray(streamBytes));

                    try
                    {
                        while (tokenizer.NextToken())
                        {
                            if (tokenizer.TokenType == PRTokeniser.TK_STRING)
                            {
                                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(strs))
                                {
                                    //exclude few words like "some text here", "page 1/2", etc before adding to stringslist
                                    bool b = excludeList.Any(st => strs.Contains(st));
                                    if (!b)
                                    {
                                        stringsList.Add(strs);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        tokenizer.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            reader.Close();
        }
```

But problem is, in `page 1`, I'm unable to read the address lines that is just on left side of the table. And in `page 2`, the data I want to extract is `not in a single line nor there are any lines drawn around` the data, just like that of in the page 1. This makes it complicated for me to get the data. When I opened this pdf file from MS Word, I got to know that the data I'm interested in, is not in a table but are separated by spaces/tabs. Also the header is placed in a rectangular box thus wrapping it.

What I want to extract -

1. Item number
2. product number
3. product description
4. quantity
5. unit price, and
6. Serial ID - can be more than 1 for each product separated by commas and lines. each line contains 4-5 serial ID's.

It would be really grateful if anyone can help me with this. Thanks in advance.

UPDATE 1: stringsList value while debugging. I don't know why I'm getting the string in last, but I can trim it before adding it to the `stringsList`

```
        [109]   "Customer ID"   string
        [110]   "Order ID"  string
        [111]   "Invoice ID"    string
        [112]   "Invoice date"  string
        [113]   "1322124343"    string
        [114]   "7649238211"    string
        [115]   "9008780520"    string
        [116]   "31 May 2019"   string
        [117]   "Item " string
        [118]   "number"    string
        [119]   "Product number"    string
        [120]   "Product description"   string
        [121]   "Quantity"  string
        [122]   "GON"   string
        [123]   "Unit price"    string
        [124]   "Net item"  string
        [125]   "price" string
        [126]   "Cry"   string
        [127]   "10"    string
        [128]   "12AG544#AAB"   string
        [129]   "Some product description goes in here" string
        [130]   "1" string
        [131]   "AD"    string
        [132]   "  1 776.00 "   string
        [133]   "   1 776.00"   string
        [134]   "USD"   string
        [135]   "AEM/PAC"   string
        [136]   "1324810291341" string
        [137]   "Customer line item "   string
        [138]   "number"    string
        [139]   "40"    string
        [140]   "USD"   string
        [141]   "-    100.56"   string
        [142]   "purchase agr disc" string
        [143]   "Net sub total" string
        [144]   "   1 675.44"   string
        [145]   "USD"   string
        [146]   "Serial ID :"   string
        [147]   "AZ123DER322"   string
        [148]   "Product total" string
        [149]   "Total product price"   string
        [150]   "1,776.00"  string
        [151]   "USD"   string
        [152]   "Total discount"    string
        [153]   "-100.56"   string
        [154]   "USD"   string
        [155]   "Shipping & Handling"   string
        [156]   "0.00"  string
        [157]   "USD"   string
        [158]   "Total net product price"   string
        [159]   "0.00"  string
        [160]   "USD"   string
        [161]   "Net sub total" string
        [162]   "1,675.44"  string
        [163]   "USD"   string
        [164]   "Total tax amount"  string
        [165]   "0.00"  string
        [166]   "USD"   string
        [167]   "Total amount to be paid for"   string
        [168]   "1,675.44"  string
        [169]   "USD"   string
```

[image: Invoice copy page 1]

[image: Invoice copy page 2]

Comment: What you request is in no way trivial and what you coded will work for exactly your "golden sample" - and probably only that (and invoices that are _very_ similar).

Comment: @Fildor: with the code that I posted, I'm unable to get all the text. I tried, not all texts I'm able to capture. while debugging, at first I saw only 100 words captured in the `stringsList` including the words that are there in the `excludeList`.

Comment: Do you have any information about the pdf source? Who creates it? Can they provide the data in machine-readable form? Working with PDFs is a pain by itself, but if you have to extract information from visually arranged tables, it will get you into trouble. How do I know? I did exactly that for ~5 years for a living. Just that we used a _specialized software_ for document analysis and data extraction. The manufacturer had an army of coders, _linguists_ and AI-Specialitsts and solutions could be put together so you used a mix of rulesets, AI, custom scripts ... just to put you into perspective.

Comment: ^^ which is of course expensive, error-prone and completely unneccessary. Because guess what: The author of that invoice probably has them created by some kind of ERP software ...

Comment: I totally agree with you. But unfortunately I don't have the source. I tried talking to sources whom I thought might know the start point. But no luck. So had to post here. BTW that's how I'm getting data into my `stringsList`.

Comment: You're best off using some sort of ML OCR software. And no, it isn't cheap.

Comment: @IanKemp: Thanks for the suggestion, but I can't afford it.

Comment: What about grabbing all text in pdf and then processing that word by word/line by line?

Comment: @AliK: as you can see the above `stringsList` values.., if I start processing word by word also, I'm not exactly sure which line has what! As the words are not read continuous and in an order in Page 2

Comment: For proper text extraction based on iText you have to either update (both the current iText 5.5.x and the current iText 7.x are ok) or implement a lot atop the library, more than sensibly fits the scope of a stack overflow answer. Generically extracting tables adds yet another level of analysis on top.

Comment: @mkl: if not iText, can you suggest me with some other good pdf library? I'm ok with some other open source library as well unless it does what I expect

Comment: *"can you suggest me with some other good pdf library?"* - For library recommendations you should ask on [softwarerecs.se]. But you should also look at commercial libraries - some of them offer inexpensive (or even free?) licenses for small scale projects.